# Is "else if" a language construct or a consequence of how the compiler treats the if/else construct?

Tags: c#, syntax

`if/else` statements are flexible in their acceptable syntax. In languages like C#, the code to execute can be on the same line as the condition check or on a new line, indented or not, within braces or not. This flexibility raises the question of whether the `else if` block is an actual language construct at all, or merely a result of just how flexible `if/else` statements are.

Consider this code:

```
// Version 1
if (condition1)
  // do something
else if (condition2)
  // do something else
else
  // do some third thing
```

This code can be rewritten in a way that is syntactically different but semantically identical:

```
// Version 2
if (condition1)
  // do something
else
{
  if (condition2)
    // do something else
  else
    // do some third thing
}
```

The braces surrounding the `else` block are optional because `if/else` is considered a single statement for brace-usage purposes, so yet another semantically identical iteration would be:

```
// Version 3
if (condition1)
  // do something
else
  if (condition2)
    // do something else
  else
    // do some third thing
```

There is, of course, no discernible difference between Version 1 and Version 3 because C# doesn't respect whitespace. The natural question, then, is whether `else if` is an actual feature built into C# (or C-family languages in general), or simply a useful consequence of flexible syntax that clever software developers discovered long ago.

I've tried writing programs to test this behavior and try to tease out the underlying behavior, but I haven't been able to write a program that can successfully differentiate between the two syntaxes. Either I'm not clever enough, or the difference is rather subtle. I have also searched for a different SE community to post this under, but none seemed appropriate.

Comment: *"the code to execute can be ... within braces or not"* only if it's a single line. Otherwise braces are required

Comment: Some languages have a separate `ElseIf` keyword. C# does not. I wouldn't call `else if` a separate language construct in C#.

Comment: @RufusL And yet, version 3 works exactly like version 1 (AFAICT) without braces. It appears that _"`if/else` is considered a single statement for brace-usage purposes"_ as the OP suggests (I actually never knew this).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Not if `// do some third thing` is made up of multiple statements, because if it were, only the first statement would be conditionally executed and the rest would exeucte every time. Same applies to the other `// do something` lines, but if those were multiple statements, you'd get a compile error because you can't have an `else` without an `if`, and the second statement would be a break from the original `if`.

Comment: @RufusL Yes, of course. Seems like that's what you meant from the beginning. I thought that you were arguing that the `else` branch in the third version does need braces anyway.

Comment: `else if` is not a language feature. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements

Comment: I was using simple statements in my example. I wasn't trying to imply that braces are _never_ necessary, only that they aren't _generally_ necessary. I'm assuming that (almost) everyone using this site knows that braces block statements together for use with conditionals, loops, etc. I didn't feel the need to spell that out just to describe a simple scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `else if` is not a language feature - it's just a different use of whitespace between the statements.

`else`, `if`, `(condition)`, and `action();` can be written on one, two, three or four lines;  it's just easier to read and takes up less vertical space to put them all on one or two lines.

Indentation is also optional, but I included it for readablility.

Interestingly (at least to me), the first example with 9 lines and the last example with 1 line are the hardest to read.

I personally prefer the third example over the second one because it feels dangerous to have a single statement after an `if` without enclosing curley braces (since if another line were added, it would not be conditionally executed).

**Example 1 (9 lines)**

```
if
    (condition1)
    DoSomething();
else
if
    (condition2)
    DoSomethingElse();
else
    DoAThirdThing();
```

---

**Example 2 (6 lines)**

```
if (condition1) 
    DoSomething();
else if (condition2) 
    DoSomethingElse();
else 
    DoAThirdThing();
```

---

**Example 3 (3 lines)**

```
if (condition1) DoSomething();
else if (condition2) DoSomethingElse();
else DoAThirdThing();
```

---

**Example 4 (1 line)**

```
if(condition1)DoSomething();else if(condition2)DoSomethingElse();else DoAThirdThing();
```

Note that the executable action portion must be enclosed in curly braces if it contains multiple statements.

Comment: I was starting to suspect that this was the case, but as I mentioned in the question, I was having a hard time devising a test that would separate the two forms. Thank you for the information. I didn't actually realize that your first example would even compile - I always assumed that it would be a syntax error.